# How to create dynamic web projects in in IntelliJIDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, artifact

I need to know if it is possible to create **dynamic web projects** (like Eclipse) in IntelliJIDEA.
I tried different solutions but with not luck.
Is there anyone who has experience on this?

[image: Eclipse dynamic web project example]

Comment: I just want to confirm. Do you have ultimate edition?

Comment: Yes i have the latest and updated version of the ultimate edition of intellij.

Comment: its weird . I hope you tried like this :https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#d5379208

Comment: The fact here is that i need to create 2 dynamic web project to link 2 different folders... I know how generally works IDEA but i'm importing the structure of this pr from eclipse.. It's bad designed but for clienent's requests i can't change the structure... :( Yes it's weird!!!!

Comment: Intellij one window one project . If you want multiple project probably you should go maven multimodule project type.

Comment: Perfect... it can help me.. i'm now trying using the import from eclipse functionaiti in IDEA..

Comment: In IntelliJ, you can't work with multiple projects in a window. But you can have multiple [modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html) in a single project. and then there are [artifacts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html) which will help you assemble your project output, an exploded war, for example. artifacts will be helpful when you have a project structure that can't be directly deployed as an application and you want to map the project files/folders to the desired deployment structure.

Comment: Ty for the answer. I will try in these days with artifacts... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone is still trying to accomplish that task, after some time I retried to simulate dynamic web projects in IntelliJ and now I have a kind of solution.
I'm using this solution to recreate my old eclipse workspace and I'm successfully using it, so you can consider it a working way.
Like someone said in the above comments we need to use artifacts. I'm using ultimate edition of IntelliJ, don't know if artifacts are available on the standard edition but i think so.

**Creating the Artifact**

- `File`
- `Project Structure`
- `Artifacts`
- click on the `+` symbol
- `Other`

That will create an *unamed* artifact

- select *unamed* and in his tab click on the `+` symbol
- choose the entry `Directory Content`
- link the folder that you want

With this process we have an artifact linked to the choosen folder.

**Deploying the Artifact**
To deploy the artifact (Tomcat deploy in my case) together the .war file:

- `Add configuration`
- `Tomcat Template`
- `Deployment`
- click on the `fix` button (if requested by IDEA)
- in the bottom of this tab you can see some tasks (generally `build` and `build :war`)
- click on the `+` symbol
- `Build Artifacts`
- Choose the artifact generated in the previous step
- click `ok`
- move the latest added task beetween the `build` and the `build:war` tasks.

Comment: How can we include a resources directory to the artifact?